# Find the last filled row in a filtered column without dropping the Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, count, rows, autofilter

How do I get the position of the last non-empty cell in a filtered column without dropping the applied Autofilter? I understand it's easy to get the number of the last **visible** row with

```
Dim ws as Worksheet, rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Letter & 1 & ":" & Letter & 1) ' where Letter is the letter code of the column
GetLastVisibleRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, rng.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
```

but I need the number of the last **filled** row instead. At the same time, I'd like to avoid setting

```
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
```

if it's possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it before filtering?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not fit. I'm not the one who applies the filter. The filtered worksheet is the input for my tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient or fastest method, but this appears to work:

```
Function GetLastCellOfColumn(ColLetter As String) As Range
    Dim Col As Range
    Dim Rw As Long
    Set Col = Range(ColLetter & ":" & ColLetter)
    Set GetLastCellOfColumn = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Col)
    For Rw = GetLastCellOfColumn.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Len(GetLastCellOfColumn.Cells(Rw).Value) > 0 Then
            Set GetLastCellOfColumn = GetLastCellOfColumn.Cells(Rw)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Note that `Len(....) > 0` will fail if the cell has an error value. I'd use `IsEmpty` instead of `Len` here to check.

Comment: There could be issues when using UsedRange in finding the actual Range of interest. Be careful applying the property.

Answer (score 1):

A charming solution by @jkpieterse plus a useful comment by @BigBen is exactly what I was looking for. Just to finalize the thread, the function returning the **row number** is

```
Function GetLastFilledCellOfColumn(ws As Worksheet, ColLetter As String) As Long
    Dim Col As Range, Urng As Range, Rw As Long
    Set Col = ws.Range(ColLetter & ":" & ColLetter)
    Set Urng = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, Col)
    For Rw = Urng.Cells.count To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(Urng.Cells(Rw)) Then
            GetLastFilledCellOfColumn = Rw
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Problem solved.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm an R & Matlab person and not Excel... could you please educate me a little bit? What are the cases when IsEmpty(Urng.Cells(Rw)) and IsEmpty(Urng.Cells(Rw).Value) will give different results?

Comment: Regarding my previously (deleted) comment, `IsEmpty(Range.Value)` is explicit, versus just `IsEmpty(Range)`.

Comment: Using .Value is *slightly* faster as you don't leave it to the VBA interpreter to first fetch the name of the default property, but tell it up front which property you want to get. I prefer it that way.

Answer (score 1):

So maybe this is an alternative way to look into:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Long: col = 2 'Change to whichever column you interested in
Dim rw as Long

With Sheet1 'Change to whichever sheets CodeName you need
    Set rng = .Range("_FilterDatabase").Columns(col)
    rw = .Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & rng.Address & "<>"""",ROW(" & rng.Address & ")))")
End With

End Sub
```

I'm afraid I rushed this a little and might have made a mistake but will have to get going. Hopefully you understand whats going on =)

---

**Edit:**

The above would definately work, but as figured out through the chat, there is actually a `ListObject` involved, called `Table1`, which throws of the `AutoFilter` range. So here are two alternative ways of doing the same thing:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Long: col = 2 'Change to whichever column you interested in
Dim rw as Long

With Sheet1 'Change to whichever sheets CodeName you need
    Set rng = .Range("Table1")
    rw = .Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & rng.Address & "<>"""",ROW(" & rng.Address & ")))")
End With

End Sub
```

Or, when you don't know the name of the table:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Long: col = 2 'Change to whichever column you interested in
Dim rw as Long

With Sheet1 'Change to whichever sheets CodeName you need
    Set rng = .ListObjects(1).Range
    rw = .Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & rng.Address & "<>"""",ROW(" & rng.Address & ")))")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for introducing the hidden named ranges to me - I was completely unaware of. As for the code, I currently get $B$1 as rng.Address while I guess it should be $B$2019 in case 2019 is the last filled cell row number. Could you suggest to fix this?

Comment: Well what range does the filter apply to and what column are you interested in? @dmitryd.onischenko. you also sure to have used the right sheet?

Comment: So I double-checked this for two possible scenarios: a) the filter is applied manually to the header row of a column (select top cell in a column and press Shift+Ctrl+L), b) the filter is applied to the whole column (select the column and press Shift+Ctrl+L). For the end-user, the functionality is the same and the filtered rows match. However, the Autofilter ranges differ in these two cases. Thus, your current solution works for the second scenario only.

Comment: @DmitryD.Onishchenko, any scenario gave me the right result, No matter if I click `Filter` in the ribbon. Selected a specific range first (even just headers) to apply the filter to or the whole columns. The result was constant and correct for me. Not sure what you did differently. This would prevent a loop through cells (which is slow) but if it doesn't work for you it's simple....don't use it =)

Comment: JvdV, here is the issue: once I create a new sample sheet with little sample data and try the two scenarios I get identical results (just as you describe). But on a specific worksheet I'm working with (a large formatted one) I get $B$1 as rng.Address for col=2. Could you suggest what sheet/column/data properties should I look at? I like your solution very much so I want to make it finalized (or to prove I was an idiot at some point :) )

Comment: Well, what does `Debug.Print .Range("_FilterDatabase").Address` return and what does `Debug.Print .Range("_FilterDatabase").Columns(col).address` return in the immediate window. The `col` variable is obviously relative to where your filterrange starts. If it start in column B, and if you interested in column B then you must refer to it as `col = 1` since thats the first column in your filtered range

Comment: `Dim col As Long: col = 2` gives
`Debug.Print .Range("_FilterDatabase").Address  ' $A$1` and
`Debug.Print rng.Address ' $B$1`.
However, the autofilter appears to be applied to all the columns on the sheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204177/discussion-between-jvdv-and-dmitry-d-onishchenko).

Comment: One problem with using the _Filterdatabase name is if the rage has never been set to autofilter, the name does not exist.